# Executing three fetch requests one after the other

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, es6-promise

I have to execute three fetch requests one after the other. That means, let's say my three fetch request are:

```
const A =  (url) => (dispatch) => {
    let req = fetch(url, ....)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw response;
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(response => {

    }).catch(error => {

    })
}


const B =  (url) => (dispatch) => {
    let req = fetch(url, ....)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw response;
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(response => {

    }).catch(error => {

    })
}


const C=  (url) => (dispatch) => {
    let req = fetch(url, ....)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw response;
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(response => {

    }).catch(error => {

    })
}
```

First "A" should get executed, then B should be executed on the completion of A, then C should be executed on the completion of B. Once A,B,C are completed, I want to execute a function

```
doSomething = () => {
//do something after A, B, C are executed
}
```

I am pretty new to "promises". Can someone please guide me on how to do this?

Below is my actual code which I tried

```
const chopSegment = (token, frame_tag_url, tag_to_delete_id, chopped_tag_array, tags_for_index_update) => (dispatch) =>  {
    let req = fetch(frame_tag_url + tag_to_delete_id + "/",
        {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Token " + token,
                "content-type": "application/json"
            }
        })
    req.then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw response;
        }
        else
            return response.json();
    }).then(response => {
        return fetch(frame_tag_url,
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Token " + token,
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                },
                body : JSON.stringify(tags_for_index_update)
            }).then(response1 => {
            if (!response1.ok) {
                throw response1;
            }
            return response1.json();
        }).then(response => {
            for(let i = 0; i < chopped_tag_array.length; i++){
                return  fetch(frame_tag_url,
                    {
                        method: "POST",
                        body: JSON.stringify(chopped_tag_array[i]),
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": "Token " + token,
                            "content-type": "application/json"
                        }
                    })
                .then(response2 => {
                    if (!response2.ok) {
                        throw response2;
                    }
                    return response2.json();
                }).then(response2 => {
                    dispatch(chopSegmentSuccess(response2))
                }).catch(error => {

                })
            }
        }).catch(error => {

        })
    }).catch(error => {
    })
}
```

In the above code, only first fecth ("DELETE") is getting executed. The subsequent fetches are not getting executed.

Comment: `A().then(() => B()).then(() => C).then(doSomething)`?

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Then give a [mre] of what you've tried and what the problem with it is.

Comment: Sure.I have attached the implemented code in the update. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Note *"minimal"*. And you say *"doesn't work"* - so what *does* happen?

Comment: Only the first fetch ("DELETE") is getting executed. The subsequent fetches are not getting executed.

Comment: You should probably log the errors in the catch, just in case the problem is the first fetch is failing. In that case, no `then()` willl be executed afterwards.

Comment: First fetch is success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track. With promises, you generally want to make the `.then` chain as linear as possible. Here is the correct way to do what you are doing with promise chains (I have refactored some functionality to ease readability)

```js
const throwIfNotOk = response => {
  if (!response.ok) throw response
  return response
}

const deleteTag = (url, token) => fetch(url, {
  method: "DELETE",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Token " + token,
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
})

const postTagForIndexUpdate = (url, tag) => fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Token " + token,
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(tag),
})

const chopSegment = (
  token,
  frame_tag_url,
  tag_to_delete_id,
  chopped_tag_array,
  tags_for_index_update,
) => dispatch => {
  return deleteTag(frame_tag_url + tag_to_delete_id + "/")
  .then(response => { return throwIfNotOk(response) })
  .then(response => { return response.json() })
  .then(() => {
    return postTagForIndexUpdate(frame_tag_url, tags_for_index_update)
  })
  .then(response => { return throwIfNotOk(response) })
  .then(response => { return response.json() })
  .then(() => {
    const promises = []
    for (let i = 0; i < chopped_tag_array.length; i++) {
      promises.push(
        postTagForIndexUpdate(frame_tag_url, chopped_tag_array[i])
        .then(response => { return throwIfNotOk(response) })
        .then(response => { return response.json() })
      )
    }
    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
  .then(response => { dispatch(response) })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle error
  })
}
```

you can get even cleaner by using a promise library like [rubico](https://github.com/richytong/rubico)

```js
import { pipe, map } from 'rubico'

const chopSegment = (
  token,
  frame_tag_url,
  tag_to_delete_id,
  chopped_tag_array,
  tags_for_index_update,
) => dispatch => pipe([
  () => deleteTag(frame_tag_url + tag_to_delete_id + "/"),
  throwIfNotOk,
  response => response.json(),
  () => postTagForIndexUpdate(frame_tag_url, tags_for_index_update),
  throwIfNotOk,
  response => response.json(),
  () => chopped_tag_array,
  map(pipe([
    chopped_tag => postTagForIndexUpdate(frame_tag_url, chopped_tag),
    throwIfNotOk,
    response => response.json(),
  ])),
  dispatch,
])
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Answer (score -1):

You should call the following "fetches" in the callback (inside "then") of the previous one, or chain them: `fetch(...).then(...).then(...)...`

You can improve the syntax by using async/await keywords. Please take a look:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function